# Group By in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Please help me to get the result like in Result table as below .

Data Table

```
CASH_ID    FK_TOUR_ID    CASH_COLLECTED    CASH_TYPE    COLLECTION_DATE    FK_COLLECTED_BY_ID
616        14500         966.6             0            5/14/2014          433
617        14500         470               1            5/14/2014          433
618        14602         546               0            5/15/2014          891
```

Result Table:

```
FK_TOUR_ID    By_Check    By_Cash    COLLECTION_DATE    FK_COLLECTED_BY_ID
14500         470         966.6      5/14/2014          433
14602                     546        5/15/2014          891
```

Comment: How to group FK_Tour_ID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by `fk_tour_id`, and then use aggregate functions to display the check and cash numbers:

```
select  fk_tour_id
,       sum(case when cash_type = 1 then cash_collected end) as [By Check]
,       sum(case when cash_type = 0 then cash_collected end) as [By Cash]
,       sum(cash_collected) as [Both Check and Cash]
,       min(collection_date)
,       min(fk_collected_by_id)
from    YourTable
group by
        fk_tour_id
```

Comment: Thank you Andomar, If i want to add one more filed in result table as "Total" , ie total= cash+check

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb801/2/0):

```
SELECT m.FK_TOUR_ID, 
(
  SELECT SUM(CASH_COLLECTED) 
  FROM MyTable AS s1 
  WHERE s1.FK_COLLECTED_BY_ID = m.FK_COLLECTED_BY_ID
  AND s1.CASH_TYPE = 1
) AS By_Check,
(
  SELECT SUM(CASH_COLLECTED) 
  FROM MyTable AS s2
  WHERE s2.FK_COLLECTED_BY_ID = m.FK_COLLECTED_BY_ID
  AND s2.CASH_TYPE = 0 
) AS By_Cash,
m.COLLECTION_DATE, m.FK_COLLECTED_BY_ID
FROM MyTable AS m
GROUP BY m.FK_TOUR_ID, m.COLLECTION_DATE, m.FK_COLLECTED_BY_ID
```